# Create map with new key from enum of maps

Tags: elixir

I have an Enum of Maps that look like this:

```
[
 %{
   "key1" => "someVal",
   "key2" => "anotherVal"
  },
 %{
   "key1" => "someVal",
   "key2" => "anotherVal"
  }
]
```

How can I change this so that the maps will be updated with new keys, but with some of the previous values

```
//New map will not have keys named `key1` or `key2` but a new set of key names
[
 %{
   "a" => "someVal",
   "b" => "anotherVal",
   "c" => 0
  },
 %{
   "a" => "someVal",
   "b" => "anotherVal",
   "c" => 0
  },
]
```

`brand_newk` is also just going to be whatever index the `Enum.map` is at.

I thought about using `Enum.with_index` and `Enum.map` and `Map.new` or `Map.put`

but not sure how to combine them all

Comment: The question is not answerable unless you tell us how you know that `"new"` should replace `"key1"` and `"val"` should replace `"key2"`, and where the keys `"new"` and `"val"` come from.

Comment: I guess I am not really replacing or renaming the keys, rather I need a map with new key names but with the same values plus a third key with a new value type not in orginal map

Comment: Yeah. So you need a way to determine which of the old key names should get which of the new key names. How do you know that it should be `"a" => "someVal"`, and not `"b" => "someVal"`?

Comment: For this example, I am just assumung that key `a` will be what was previously `key1` and `b` will be what was `key2` and `c` is just a brand new entry

Comment: Alright. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can call [`Enum.with_index/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#with_index/2) to pair each map with its index, and then use [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) to map each of those maps to the map with new keys, like this:

```elixir
[
  %{
    "key1" => "someVal",
    "key2" => "anotherVal"
  },
  %{
    "key1" => "someVal",
    "key2" => "anotherVal"
  }
]
|> Enum.with_index()
|> Enum.map(fn {map, index} ->
  %{
    "a" => map["key1"],
    "b" => map["key2"],
    "c" => index
  }
end)
```

Output:

```elixir
[
  %{"a" => "someVal", "b" => "anotherVal", "c" => 0},
  %{"a" => "someVal", "b" => "anotherVal", "c" => 1}
]
```

Comment: I updated OP. The example I provided assumes two of the key names will be similar, but they will all be new key names different from the original map

Comment: OK, then you need to tell us where the new key names come from, and how to decide which of the old key names should be updated.

Comment: The new key names will come from no where. All three of the keys in the second map example are new and replace the ones on the original map, so would I just have to use `Map.put` 3 times? |> Map.put() |> Map.put() |> Map.put()